# How to move data in tables during deployment with minimal downtime and loss of functionality?

Tags: deployment, architecture, data-migration

Working in a project that's already live with data, it's not uncommon project requirements change, and force you to change table structure.

My question is how during deployment, you move data from old table schema to new table schema, and at the same time apply migration with minimal downtime? By downtime, I mean the time your app will be inaccessible, resulting in errors.

Let's assume you have a database migration task that takes care of migration (reverts MySQL statements if migration fails).

I am not talking about renaming database columns, because in that case database would simply rename the column without losing any data.

## Consider this scenario:

original table `post` with 2 million entries:

```
| name | slug | content | tags |
```

`tags` is a `text` column where tags are added comma separated.

To make things more clear, you decide `tags` need to be a separate table, and create a `postTag` table like this:

### tags

```
| id | name |
```

### postTag

```
| postId | tagId | # both are foreign keys
```

I know scenario database structure is bad design from the start, I just thought it as an imaginary scenario to illustrate my point.

## Possible solution 1

Would a possible solution be, to copy and rename old table, and execute a script via some sort of hook to take care of data migration? I think that wouldn't work especially if there were foreign keys involved in that table. Of course you could temporarily disable foreign key checks, but it doesn't sound like a solid solution.

Also, since we have 2 million entries, script would take a lot of time, meaning our downtime would extend.

## Possible solution #2

What if we use an entirely separate database? Initially we'd replicate the production database (or simply copy it if possible), once replication is 100% synced, disable replication, and run our migration script on the second database. Change database environment variables to point to our 2nd database during deployment, and after that delete first database.

A possible problem I can think of this approach, is: this is a *LIVE* site! what happens to new data added on database #1, until migration on database #2 is completed? It is possible we lose important data. Of course we could simply ask our authors, not to add any posts at that time, but what if it was a forum were users contribute content? We'd have to shut down some functionality in order to do that which, again means more "downtime".

I'd greatly appreciate any insights on this issue.

P.S.: I have done a similar task before: it was moving data from a legacy application to a new application. New application wasn't live so migration was easier.

Comment: "since we have 2 million entries, script would take a lot of time" - what do you mean by a lot of time here? Is it feasible to lock the system for writes during the migration period and do that migration over the night/weekend when the app is less busy?

Comment: @AdrianMitev thanks for your comment! let's consider this app gets deployments several times per day (so doing the migration over the weekend is not an option), and we need to limit loss of functionality/locking down writes as much as possible.

Comment: How would you do a data migration that takes longer when you deploy multiple times during the day?

Comment: @AdrianMitev you're totally right, the reason I said that was to emphasize the fact that migration won't wait until the weekend where the app is less busy.

Comment: There isn't a win-win situation here. You have to do tradeoffs.